# Is every continuous bijection a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Is  every  continuous  bijection is homeomorphism ?

my attempt : Yes,  take  $(a,b)$  and $(c,d)$  that is  Define  a function $f : (a,b) \rightarrow  (c,d)$  and take  $f(x) = c + (d-c) \frac{(x-a)}{(b-a)}$ for  $x \in (a,b)$ . It is clear that $f$ is continuous bijection similarly  we can proved the  $f^{-1}$ also

Comment: You only investigate the case of both spaces being open intervals (and so homeomorphic to begin with) ans even only affine linear maps instead of more general continuous maps

Comment: See this post: [Continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2901914/9464)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $X=[0,2\pi)$, $Y=S^1$ and $f\colon X\to Y$, $x\mapsto e^{ix}$.

Comment: But here  X  is not closed  i mean not closed interval  but  Y  is  closed and compact

Comment: @jasmine: But what you asked was only “is every continuous bijection a homeomorphism?” You can’t expect people to read your mind and figure out that you had extra conditions that you did not explicitly state.

Comment: Okss  sir @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1):

No, but in the case where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection of a compact space and a Hausdorff space it is.