# Embedded submanifolds: the circle into $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology

I struggle to wrap my head around homeomorphisms and embeddings.
Especially I considered the circle and how to embed it into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider the function $f: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; x \mapsto (\cos x,\sin x)$. This is no homeomorphism since $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Another way of seeing that no homeomorphism exists can be seen by observing $[0,2\pi)$ is open but $f([0,2\pi))$ is nether open nor closed. [Wikipedia/Homeomorphism][1] and [Stackoverflow][2]

Is this deduction correct?

The real confusion begins now.
Because $f$ is not a homeomorphism, it cannot be an embedding, which are homeomorphisms onto their images.([Wikipedia/Homeomorphism][3])
However, some authors argue the opposite; see, for example, [Link, Example 3.2 end] [4].
Thus, I suppose I misunderstood something.

If I'm correct that $f$ is no embedding of the unit circle onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ how can it be shown that the circle can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or more general how can one show that $S^{n-1}$ (the (n-1)-dimensional unit sphere) can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$?

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Notes
[2]: [Wrongly showing that an interval has a homeomorphism to $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527762/wrongly-showing-that-an-interval-has-a-homeomorphism-to-s1)
  [3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology
  [4]: [https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2019/REUPapers/Smith,Zoe.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2019/REUPapers/Smith,Zoe.pdf)

Comment: You say yourself, an embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image. So you should look at the map $[0,2\pi) \rightarrow f([0,2\pi)); x \mapsto (\cos x,\sin x)$. Is that a homoeomorphism?

Comment: What is $f^{-1}$? Its domain would be $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I would claim that $f: [0,2\pi)→f([0,2\pi));\mapsto (\cos x,\sin x)$ is a homoeomorphism. Since i have a inverse everywhere on f([0,2\pi)). If the we have $f: [0,2\pi)→\mathbb{R}^2$ we don't even have an inverse defined for the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it is not onto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you should start with reading precisely what a homeomorphism and embedding are:

1. A function $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism if it is invertible, continuous and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
2. Typically, a function $f:X\to Y$ is called an embedding if $f$, as a function $X\to f(X)$, is a homeomorphism.

Note that evey homeomorphism is an embedding, but not vice versa.

It is important for you to understand the role of $Y$ here. If $f$ is not "onto", then it is not invertible, and thus not a homeomorphism. It still can be an embedding though.

> Consider the function $f: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; x \mapsto (\cos x,\sin x)$. This is no homeomorphism since $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Incorrect. This is not a homeomorphism because it is not invertible: forget about $f^{-1}$ being continuous, it doesn't exist! Because the image is not whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ is not "onto".

And it is not an embedding, because its image is $S^1$, and $f$ (as a function $[0,2\pi)\to S^1$) indeed does not have a continuous inverse.

And in fact if $f:[0,2\pi)\to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $S^1$ as its image, then $f$ is not an embedding, regardless of how $f$ is defined. Because then it would induce a homeomorphism $[0,2\pi)\to S^1$, but $S^1$ is compact while $[0,2\pi)$ is not.

> The real confusion begins now. Because $f$ is not a homeomorphism, it cannot be an embedding, which are homeomorphisms onto their images.

Homeomorphism onto image **is not** a homeomorphism. Embedding **is not** a homeomorphism in general. I mean, read again your claim carefuly. You say "not homeomorphism $\Rightarrow$ not embedding", or equivalently "embedding $\Rightarrow$ homeomorphism". And so is the term "embedding" and "homeomorphism" the same? Of course not. But yeah, I understand how this naming convention can be confusing.

> how can it be shown that the circle can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Well, the circle, or any sphere is defined as

$$S^n=\big\{v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\ \big|\ \lVert v\rVert =1\big\}$$

and so there is one obvious candidate: the inclusion

$$i:S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
$$i(x)=x$$

It is an embedding, because the image is $S^1$ and $i^{-1}=i$ (on image).

It is not a homeomorphism, because $i$, as a function $S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to rephrase it to be sure that I understand correctly. A function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an homeomorphism if it is invertible, continuous and with continuous inverse $f^{-1}$ on the **whole** $Y$. Embeddings are homeomorphisms onto their image which basically requires the softened requirement that $f$ needs to be invertible, continuous and with continuous inverse $f^{-1}$ **only** on $f(X) \subset Y$. That's also why you responded which "Incorrect. This...". Since $f$ is not "onto" i cannot even send every point back to $[0,2\pi]$, but only the subset $f(X)$.

Comment: Additionally, for further understanding: Consider $f: [0,2\pi] \rightarrow S^1; x\mapsto (\sin x, \cos x)$ and $i: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; i(x)=x$. Then, the function $h = i \circ f; [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; x \mapsto i(f(x))$ is an embedding of $[0,2\pi]$ into $ \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Unfortunately, did a typo $[0,2\pi]$ should be $[0,2\pi)$ everywhere.

Comment: @rath3t $h$ is not an embedding for the same reason that $f$ is not - $h(0)$ is very close to $h(2\pi-\varepsilon)$, so $h^{-1}$ cannot be continuous. Note that something must be wrong, because $i \circ f = f$.

Comment: Ok then, i didn't completely get it. I suppose my misunderstanding has something to do with the boundary, as you tried to explain to me with $h(0)$ and $h(2\pi-\epsilon)$. If have the coord pair $(x,y) \in f([0,2\pi))$, if i run along  $f([0,2\pi))$ with these and map these back to $[0,2\pi)$ via $f^{-1}$. If i don't see a jump it is continuous. I don't jump over $f(2\pi)$ since it is not in my set. If i would have a function, $f:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; x\rightarrow (x,0)$ i would witness the same, wouldn't I? Here the conclusion would then also be that this $f$ is no embedding?

Comment: I don't see why then the "non-existing" jump is a problem in the former case, since I don't require the last point in the set.

Comment: @rath3t your first comment is correct. As for your further comments and $h$ example: $h$ is an embedding if $h$ with its image restricted is a homeomorphism. But if you restrict the image to $S^1$, then $i:S^1\to S^1$ is the identity. Meaning $h=f$ when you restrict the image. And so it doesn't have continuous inverse for exactly same reasons.

Comment: @rath3t note that if $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding, then (by definition) $f$ as a function $X\to f(X)$ is a homeomorphism. So there's a more elegant way to see that your $h$ cannot be an embedding, because otherwise we would have a homeomorphism $[0,2\pi)\to S^1$ which is not possible because $S^1$ is compact while $[0,2\pi)$ is not.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment. I understand the arguments that homeomorphisms preserve topological invariants and thus, $[0,2\pi)$ and $S^1$ cannot be homeomorphic. My confusion is not directly related to $S^1$. If want to embed $[0,2\pi)$ and can use the function $f: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2; (\sin x,\cos x)$. This is a homeomorphism between $[0,2\pi)$ and $f([0,2\pi))$ and thus it is an embedding, but obviously not of $S^1$. What i wanted to think about above in my second comment, is that i actually can embed $[0,2\pi)$ in $S^1$ and then this set can also be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thus I embedded $[0,2\pi)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Sorry for my detailed queries and thanks for your time!

Comment: @rath3t you can embed $[0,2\pi)$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not through the $x\mapsto(\sin x,\cos x)$ function. Because the image of this map is $S^1$ - that function **is not** a homeomorphism between $[0,2\pi)$ and $f([0,2\pi))$. You can embed it through for example $x\mapsto (x,0)$. You can also embed $[0,2\pi)$ into $S^1$ through for example $x\mapsto (\sin x/2, \cos x/2)$ - note that the image is not entire $S^1$.

Comment: Btw, you should also note that if $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding and $f$ is "onto", then clearly $f$ is a homeomorphism. In particular there is no embedding $[0,2\pi)\to S^1$ with $S^1$ as its image.

Comment: @freakish Ah ok now i understand (hopefully). If I'm not mistaken I can embed $(0,2\pi)$ with $x\mapsto (\sin x, \cos x)$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @rath3t yes, that's correct!

Comment: @freakish Thanks a lot!